# How to upload an image with text to Firebase to specific user swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a `Group` of `textfields`, and I already can upload it to my collection `items` in Firebase, also I have an `ImagePicker`, I can choose photo but I can't upload it to my Storage to get `URL` for `userId` to use it in the future.

```
        Group {
            Section(header: Text("New Item")) {
                TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.singleitem.title)
                TextField("Description", text: $viewModel.singleitem.description)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Author")) {
                TextField("Author", text: $viewModel.singleitem.author)
            }
            
            if mode == .edit {
                Section {
                    Button("Delete item") { self.presentActionSheet.toggle() }
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            
        }
```

**Then I tried this part of code to do it from documentation of Firebase...**

```
    private func persistImageToStorage() {
//      let filename = UUID().uuidString
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: uid)
        guard let imageData = self.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.loginStatusMessage = "Failed to push image to Storage: \(err)"
                return
            }
            
            ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                if let err = err {
                    self.loginStatusMessage = "Failed to retrieve downloadURL: \(err)"
                    return
                }
                
                self.loginStatusMessage = "Successfully stored image with url: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                print(url?.absoluteString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**...to use this thing to execute `persistImageToStorage()`, the same like I upload my text to Firebase:**

```
func handleDoneTapped() {
  self.viewModel.handleDoneTapped()
  self.persistImageToStorage()
  self.dismiss()
```

**But it's also not works..**

**This is how I call method to add items (currently able only text)**

```
class NewItemView: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Public properties
  
  @Published var singleitem: SningleItem
  @Published var modified = false
  
  // MARK: - Internal properties
  
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
  // MARK: - Constructors
  
    init(singleitem: SningleItem = SningleItem(title: "", author: "", description: "", image: "")) {
    self.singleitem = singleitem
    
      self.$singleitem
      .dropFirst()
      .sink { [weak self] singleitem in
        self?.modified = true
      }
      .store(in: &self.cancellables)
  }
  
  // MARK: - Firestore
  
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
  private func addItem(_ singleitem: SningleItem) {
    do {
        var addedItem = singleitem
        addedItem.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        _ = try db.collection("items").addDocument(from: addedItem)
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
    
  
  private func updateItem(_ singleitem: SningleItem) {
    if let documentID = singleitem.id {
      do {
          try db.collection("items").document(documentID).setData(from: singleitem)
      }
        
      catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func updateOrAddItem() {
      if singleitem.id != nil {
      self.updateItem(self.singleitem)
    }
    else {
      addItem(singleitem)
    }
  }
  
  private func removeItem() {
    if let documentID = singleitem.id {
      db.collection("items").document(documentID).delete { error in
        if let error = error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - UI handlers
  
  func handleDoneTapped() {
    self.updateOrAddItem()
  }
  
  func handleDeleteTapped() {
    self.removeItem()
  }
  
    
    
}
```

**SingleItem**

```
struct SingleItem: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title : String
    var author : String
    var description : String
    @ServerTimestamp var createdTime: Timestamp?
    var userId : String?
    var image : String
}
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case author
    case description = ""
    case image
  }
```

**Сan someone explain what the problem is? Thanks.**

Comment: "But it's also not works.." -- *what* doesn't work? The function doesn't get called? You get an error message in the function? Things don't happen in the order that you expect them to?

Comment: `persistImageToStorage()` is what is called an **asynchronous function**, due to `ref.putData` and also `ref.downloadURL`. Look it up, what it does and how to use such function. Hint, wait until it has the results before trying to use them or print them.

Comment: @jnpdx still can upload only text with code what I have.. images are not uploading into the database, idk why and its a question, whats wrong with my code? 
bc I cant understand :c

Comment: "images are not uploading into the database". Do you hit an error? Have you used the debugger to see which lines get hit in your callback function?

Comment: @jnpdx no errors... nothing there, its just not working like I said

Comment: Did you use the debugger to see what lines get hit?

Comment: can you add a `print("\(imageData)")` in `persistImageToStorage()` just after `guard let imageData = self.image?...` to see 
if you actually have an image to upload.

Comment: Best practice on SO is for you to perform troubleshooting before posting questions, and include that troubleshooting in the question. Saying 'the code doesn't work' doesn't provide us enough information to narrow the issue. Please add a breakpoint in the code and then step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected. Include which specific line is causing the issue. Note: because of this line `guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }` your entire app could silently fail and you'll never know why.